# Having Trouble with Python Classes

Tags: python, class, pygame

So I am making a simple "Dodge the Meteor Game" with Python 27 and Pygame. So everything ran smoothly, until I wanted to make classes, so I could make multiple meteors without retyping the same code. After I did this, when I run it, it stops responding with no error message. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import random

pygame.init()

width,height = 800,600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Fifteen Minute Game ")
gameStart = False

bg = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\DEREK\Desktop\Python\\space.jpg")
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg,(900,600))

x = 300
y = 300
move_x = 0
move_y = 0

playerspeed = 3

pellet_x = random.randint(0,800)
pellet_y = random.randint(0,550)

player = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (255,255,255), (x,y,30,30) )
pellet = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (255,255,255),      (pellet_x,pellet_y,15,15) )

count = 0

#Functions
def pelletxy():
    global pellet_x, pellet_y
    pellet_x = random.randint(0,770)
    pellet_y = random.randint(0,570)

def collision(rect1,rect2):
    global player, count, pellet
    if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
        if rect2 == pellet:
            pelletxy()
            count +=1

class Meteor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.meteor_x = random.randint(0,800)
        self.meteor_y = 0
        self.meteorfall = 3
        self.meteor = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (255,255,255), (self.meteor_x,self.meteor_y,35,35) )

    def collision(self,rect1,rect2):
        if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
            if rect2 == self.meteor:
                print "Good Game"
                print "MUA HAHAHAHA"
                print ""
                print "Your score:" + str(count)
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    def meteorxy(self):
        self.meteor_x = random.randint(0,800)
        self.meteor_y = 0

    def render(self):
        self.meteor_y += self.meteorfall
        self.meteor
        if meteor_y > 600:
            meteorxy()

m1 = Meteor()    

#Game Loop
while gameStart:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        # Keyboard Movement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                move_y -= playerspeed
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                move_y += playerspeed
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_x -= playerspeed
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_x += playerspeed

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                move_y = 0
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                move_y = 0
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_x = 0
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_x = 0

#Calculate new position  
x = x + move_x 
y = y + move_y

#Stop Movement on boundaries 
if x > 830:
    x = -30
elif x < -30:
    x = 830
elif y < -30:
    y = 630
elif y > 630:
    y = -30

#Check Different Collision Scenarios
collision(player, pellet)
m1.collision(player, m1.meteor)

#Draw the things onto the screen
gameDisplay.blit(bg,(0,0))

player = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (255,255,255), (x,y,30,30) )

pellet_outline = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (255,255,255), ((pellet_x - 1), (pellet_y - 1), 17,17))
pellet = pygame.draw.rect( gameDisplay, (0,0,255), (pellet_x,pellet_y,15,15) )

m1.render

pygame.display.update()
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I know it is with the classes. Thanks in advance

Hobby Programmer, Derek

Comment: How do you "know it is with the classes"? The fact that it "stops responding with no error message" suggests to me that you may be getting stuck in an infinite loop. What happens if you put some print statements at different places in your your `while`/`for` loops?

Comment: Thanks, It was with the while loop. I accidentally set the gamestart variable as False. Everything works but no meteors appear when I run it.

Comment: I have found a solution to my own problem. It was a careless mistake, as I forgot to put () after the m1.render() function. But thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

```
if event.key == K_RIGHT:
    move_x = 0

#Calculate new position  
x = x + move_x 
y = y + move_y
```

See how the indentation changes? In Python, indentation is very important. Because all of your code after the line 'move_x = 0' is not indented adequately, it is not part of your while loop; therefore, it does not get executed in the loop. Fix your indentation.

Comment: I forgot to indent it while copying the code, but I do have it on the original. But it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's probably because `gameStart` is always `False`. So you're never getting into the game loop.

You should get to know debugging. You can use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or any IDE like Eclipse. The important thing is that it can help you understand what code is being running.